# DAX expression for Yesterday's sales using selling days field

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a calendar table with a YR_Days field which assigns a selling day number for every invoice date. I need help with a DAX expression to calculate total yesterday sales using the YR_Days field. Example data below:

| InvoiceDate | YR_DAYS |
| --- | --- |
| 11/1/2022 | 200 |
| 11/2/2022 | 201 |
| 11/3/2022 | 202 |
| 11/4/2022 | 202 |
| 11/5/2022 | 202 |
| 11/6/2022 | 203 |
| 11/7/2022 | 204 |
| 11/8/2022 | 205 |
| 11/9/2022 | 206 |

In the example above, looking at a report for yesterday's sales on 11/6 would show a combined total for 11/3-11/5 since they all have a selling day of 202. However, on 11/7 that report would only show yesterday's sales for 11/6 (203).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this measure:

```
Yesterdays Sales = 
VAR yesterdays_yr_days = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Table'[YR_DAYS]),
        'Table'[InvoiceDate] < MAX('Table'[InvoiceDate])
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[Sales]),
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[YR_DAYS] = yesterdays_yr_days
        //,'Table'[InvoiceDate] < MAX('Table'[InvoiceDate])
    )
```

The above formula assumes that you want to have the same sales amount for 11/6, 11/5 and 11/4 since these days all refer to the same selling day number. If you only want to consider past invoice dates, un-comment the penultimate line by removing the //.

Comment: Did the answer help to solve your problem?